# Compiling pubsub with py2exe

Tags: python, wxpython, publish-subscribe, pypubsub

I use wx.lib.pubsub (Windows, Python 2.6)

When run my app with interpreter, the version of pubsub is 1

When i compile and run my app, the version of pubsub is 3

Why ?
How can i force compiled version to run pubsub api v1 ?

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from distutils.core import Distribution

setup(
       console=[
            dict(
                script='test.py'
                )
        ],
       options={
              'py2exe': {
                  'packages' : [
                                'wx.lib.pubsub'
                                ],
                  'includes': [],
                  "excludes" : [],
                  "dll_excludes": [ 'tcl85.dll', 'tk85.dll', 'mswsock.dll', 'powrprof.dll']
                  }
              },
       )


from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

publisher = pub.Publisher()
print pub.PUBSUB_VERSION

EVENT_NAME = "test_pubsub"

def listener(data):
    print data

publisher.subscribe(listener, EVENT_NAME)
publisher.sendMessage(EVENT_NAME, data="toto")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using a 3-year old version of wxPython. The pubsub that 2.8.12 includes is no longer supported. Use "pip install pypubsub" to install the latest pubsub, and replace "from wx.lib.pubsub import pub" by "from pubsub import pub". The [documentation about migrating from v1 to v3](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/usage/howtos/upgrade_v1tov3.html#label-upgrade-for-wx)  will probably be useful. Then it should work.